# New string formatting methodology

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through "Python 101" by Mathew Driscoll and have ran into an issue when I try this.

```
>>> print("%(lang)s is fun!" % {"lang":"python"})
```

I understand i'm trying to use the Python dictionary here with lang being a "key value pair"
All i'm doing is copying whats in the book but, the book has been out awhile and I'm using the newest version of Python.

This is the error I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    print("%(lang)s is fun!" % {"lang":"python"})
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You may also want to look into `format()` and its [formatting language](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec), AKA new style string formatting that is intended to replace the legacy `%` approach.

Answer (score 3):

You named a variable `print`. Don't do that (in general, never name a variable with the same name as a Python built-in, so no variables named `str`, `int`, `list`, `set`, `dict`, etc.). To fix your current interpreter session, run:

```
del print
```

which will remove the `print` variable shadowing the built-in `print` function, restoring the original `print` function. Then that line will run fine.